# Nhibernate: building a List<string> through <component>

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

If I have a field in the db which stores a set of comma separated strings (says tags), how can I instruct fluent Nhibernate to pick it up at `List<string>()`
e.g.

```
Public IList<string> Tags {get; set;}
```

Db field values:

```
Mvc, .net, FNH
```

Answer (score 2):

`IUserType` is what you're looking for.

You'll need to implement that interface to provide a mapping from/to the comma separated strings from/to the List.

Personally, I'd leave it alone and project the tags as IEnumerable using a Regex.

Answer (score 1):

From [NHusers](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/c09626f1ac04eeb2) list:

One method:

```
private string NonRelationalTags 
{ get  { return joinlist(Tags); } 
set
{Tags = parselist(value);}}
```

map this with NH using normal
 or equivalent.